# I am not getting data from cloud firestore

Tags: java, android-studio, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I am designing an social media application in which i have profile data for others i.e username , useremail and profile pic and i am also displying profile pic in back of the dp (as back image). i have all data of logged in user in cloud Firestore but when i login with email and password of a user the data of logged in user is not showing means it is not fetching data from cloud firestore.
here is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         getCurrentUserDetails();
    }

    private void    getCurrentUserDetails()
        {
            try {
                CurrentUserEmail = getCurrentLoggedInUser();
                if (CurrentUserEmail.equals("No user is logged in"))
                {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No user is logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginPage.class));
                finish();
            }
                else
                {
                    header_progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    objectDocumentReference=objectFirebaseFireStore.collection("UserProfileData")
                            .document(CurrentUserEmail);
                    objectDocumentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        header_userName.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("username"));
                        header_userName.setAllCaps(true);
    
                        header_user_email.setText(CurrentUserEmail);
                        String linkOfProfileImage=documentSnapshot.getString("profileimageurl");
                        Glide.with(MainContentPage.this).load(linkOfProfileImage).into(header_ProfilePic);
                            Glide.with(MainContentPage.this).load(linkOfProfileImage).into(header_backgroundProfile);
                            header_progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainContentPage.this, "Loading User Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
    
            }
    
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "MainContentPage:"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    
        }
        private String getCurrentLoggedInUser()
        {
            try
            {
                if(objectFirebaseAuth!=null)
                {
                    return objectFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail().toString();
                }
                else
                {
                    return "No user is logged in";
    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "MainContentPage:"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: And neither of `onSuccess` or `onFailure` is getting called?

Comment: yes both are not getting called but i have invoked the getCurrentUserDeatils() method.what should i do